# How to place a <div> to the right of an input field

Tags: css

this is a CSS question.

I have a form, and after each label I have a $ so that I can show a dollar sign before each text input field. However, it's showing up like this:

```
Label
$
input field
```

How can I make the '$' `<div>` be IN FRONT OF the input field?

I tried floating the $ `<div>` left and making the input go right but that did nothing. I tried changing the width of the two items but that didn't help either. `Display: inline-block` further did nothing...

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is it especially needed to use the div **after** the label to include the dollar sign? Because something like this solves the problem smoothly: https://jsfiddle.net/e7smr73s/

Comment: It's unclear what you want. When you shout "IN FRONT OF" do you mean BEFORE, AFTER or ON TOP? I'm not sure which part of a form is the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div,input{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>$</div>
  <input type="text" >
 </form>
```

give display:inline-block to both input and div, in case it has alignment issue add vertical-align:top;

Answer (score 0):

you can use display:flex and do it as follows

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>$</div>
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

Hope this helps